# Muti-dimensional Array

Tags: c

I have a trouble regarding to multi-dimensional array in C.
We have to make a multi-dimensional array in which in which the user has to input the size of the array. After that according to the size C has to create a multi-dimensional array. Remember, in the center there always has to be '1'.
At every side of one there should be '2'. on every side of '2' there should be '3', depends upon the size of array. Also shown in image. 
 can locate the mid point of an array but when i do this: `int Array[size/2][size/2]` it gives me error. and how i can adjust other 2,3 and and other numbers at the sides?

This is the code I have written for now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
 const size;
 printf("Enter the size: ");
 scanf("%d", &size);
 int Grid[size][size];
 Grid[size/2][size/2] = 1;
 printf("%d", Grid[1][1]);
 return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){

const size;
printf("Enter the size: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
int Grid[size][size];
Grid[size/2][size/2] = 1;
printf("%d", Grid[1][1]);
return 0;
}

Comment: @anaranjada done, checkout now, please.

Comment: Looks pretty good. I suggested an edit that you can review to take out some of the extra space.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &size);` is an error because `size` is `const`.  Change to `int size;`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shall not do such a thing in C :

```
int grid[size][size];
```

If you're interested in knowing why, look at **C11's Initialization** paragraph :

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.
>
> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

Then, I'm not a fan of

```
 const size;
```

Since the type is not explicit and your variable **isn't const** here. Even if you're using `scanf`, you **do modify** the value of `size` during the function.

---

But then, let's hit the problem ;)

I suggest you use a function to allocate your array. It will help clarifying your code :

```
int**   create_array(int    size)
{
  int   i;
  int** array;

  i = 0;
  // You allocate the first dimension of your array
  // (the one that will contain other arrays)
  array = malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
  if (array != NULL)
    {
      while (i < size)
        {
          // You allocate each 'sub-array' that will contain... ints !
          array[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
          i += 1;
        }
    }
   return (array);
}
```

Now this function returns a well-allocated array of the size you want. Don't forget to check if it's `NULL` in your calling function, and to free it (if it *has been* allocated).

To free the array, I'll let you write the function yourself, since it is very similar to the initialization. But still, be careful considering some sub-array might be `NULL`!

Then the initialization. The most simple way I can think of is iterating on your array and calculating the delta from the center.

```
int most_far;

////
/// Insert the loop stuff here...
//
if (x == size/2 && y == size/2)
  array[x][y] = 1;
else
  {
    // You could use a ternary here but I don't know if you're familiar with them
    // You're getting the position that is the most far from center...
    if (abs(x - size/2) > abs(y - size/2))
       most_far = abs(x - size/2);
    else
       most_far = abs(y - size/2);
    // With this position, you calculate the 'distance' between the center and your position.
    // This distance is your number ! :D
    array[x][y] = most_far;
  }
 //
 /// End of the loop, interations, etc...
 ////
```

**Little tip** : I suggest you do the population stuff in some function that returns a boolean. This boolean will be false if one sub-array has been found `NULL` during the population. And if it's the case, you probably don't want to read/display it !

Pfiouh, what a massive answer I wrote !
Hope it won't scare you (and that you'll find some help in it)

Answer (score 0):

If your targeted element is in position `a[2][2]` then the condition will be some what like this.
Consider `i` to be row and  `j` to be column.

```
 if(a[i+1][j]==a[i+1][j+1]==a[i+1][j-1]==a[i][j+1]==a[i][j-1]==a[i-1][j]==a[i-1][j+1]==a[i-1][j-1])
       flag=1;   \\any process you want
```

and you can only assign **constant** to an array while declaring it. You can't assign a value like

```
int array[size/2][size/2];
```

Comment: i didn't get your loop thingy, can you please elaborate more? thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this you might consider:

1. Filling entries in a growing square. (i.e., filling all the 1s, then the 2s, then the 3s, ...)
2. Figuring out a "formula" or procedure for each row.

Looking at the first method:

```
void fillSquare(int **arr, int n, int size)
{
    fillSquareTopSide(arr, n, size);
    fillSquareLeftSide(arr, n, size);
    fillSquareRightSide(arr, n, size);
    fillSquareBottomSide(arr, n, size);
}
```

where `n` is the current number (`1`, `2`, or `3`) and size is `3`. And then a possible implementation of `fillSquareTopSide`:

```
void fillSquareTopSide(int **arr, int n, int size)
{
    for(int i = size - n; i < size + n; i++)
        arr[size - n][i] = n;
}
```